# Regarding Visa cancellation

Tags: visas, cancellations

I live in Sri lanka and my husband will return to kuwait but he doesn't want me to come to kuwait. He is planning to cancel my visa. How long does it take him to cancel my visa if he got there and what are the possibilities of me entering kuwait in the mean time. Are there any exceptions or possibilities for me to get to kuwait? I need to come to kuwait due to personal reasons.

Comment: I have no knowledge about the time it would take but in your spot I would try to travel at earliest opportunity and then wonder if a divorce is the right thing to apply for.

Comment: Your situation is quite unclear. What is the citizenship of your husband? Yours? Have you ever lived in Kuwait? What kind of visa do you have? Based on what little information you provided, the situation can range from he can’t do anything at all about it to he just has to make a phone call.